# How to Get OS X to Automatically Install Java 7 on App Launch Instead of Java 6

Tags: java, macos

Java is no longer installed by default on OS X, but fortunately if a user tries to launch a Java app, they receive the following message:

[image]

I really like this, as is clearly explains that Java is required and provides a one-click way to install it. It's simple and painless for end users.

However, this prompts to install Java SE 6 rather than Java SE 7, which has been out for some time. This even happens on OS 10.9.1, the latest version as of this writing. I'm considering making my app require Java SE 7, but I want to ensure that users will be downloading the proper version (I'm aware I can bundle the JRE, but I would prefer not to add it since it would quadruple the app size). Ideally, I'd like for the dialog box shown above to continue to be shown, but instead of downloading Java SE 6, it downloads Java SE 7.

I tried changing the `JVMVersion` key in the Info.plist file of my application to `1.7+`, but that didn't make any difference and it still prompted to download Java SE 6 (which if it actually did require it, would result in an incompatibility).

So is there a way that I can get OS X to prompt the user to download Java 7 when they launch my app? To be clear, I want this to be something on the user side. I know that I can install Java, but I want it so that it is as painless as possible to the end user.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to automatically download Java 7 on OS X. This is by design. When you deploy an OS X application, you are expected to put everything that is required for the app to launching into the app bundle — inclusive of the JRE or JDK if you need it. If you find that the size of the JRE or JDK is unacceptable, you can prune out any components you don't need (JavaFX, AWT, JObjC, etc).

This is the most painless user experience you can offer. Download, double-click, and go.

Comment: How do you prune the size of an embedded JRE? [Oracle's instructions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html) for bundling an app don't mention it. (I can ask this in another question if it would be better.)